# grails: making database field order match constraints field order

Tags: grails

I'm very surprised that the database field order (mysql) does not match the field order specified in the static constraints area of a domain class.   Am I doing something wrong or ?  Please advise, thanks.

Please note grails has a schema-export command one can test with, which should is not database related.

(using grails 2.2.4)

Comment: I don't think that this has changed since earlier versions, but order of constraints it's not maintained when doing validation and showing error messages. At least as far as I can remember, the order was alphabetical but I read somewhere that the behaviour should be changed to maintain order in constraints for validation, but in all tests I've made this is not true..

Comment: Hmm I wonder when they are going to change it.

Comment: That's a good question. I saw yesterday a Jira exactly with this problem and it's supposed to be fixed in grails 2.0, but I don't think that's true...

Comment: I'm surprised it's not a short change for them to put out the fields to the database in an order that matches constraints.  Thoughts?